# Why deleted key in a object is still accessible in below example?

Tags: javascript

In the below given code, after deleting `objA.foo`,
it is still accessible

```js
var objA = Object.create({
  foo: 'foo'
});
var objB = objA;
objB.foo = 'bar';

delete objA.foo;
console.log(objA.foo);
console.log(objB.foo);
```

Comment: `foo` you are getting is from `prototype` chain of the original object not from the `objB`.

Answer (score 3):

You create object A with a prototype object that has a "foo" property. Then you add a *local* "foo" property to the object, and that's what's affected by the `delete`. (Note that object A and object B are the exact same object; the assignment does not make a copy.)

The subsequent references to the property "foo" are resolved at the prototype object, not object A itself.

Comment: @lfaruki there's nothing wrong with the original grammar :)